# Change label with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked for answers but couldn't find anything. I am trying to change the text I have in a label, but to no success

**HTML**

```
<li id="123" class="xxx">
  <label class="xxx" for="xxx">Something</label>
</li>
```

**Current Javascript**

```
<script>
documentquerySelector("li#field_2_31 label").innerHTML = 'New label';
</script>
```

Comment: changing the text should happen when? that answer will lead to an event e.g., on click of a button, on load of the window etc, so you got to listen for those events and then execute the change of text. So when should it happen?? also you got a wrong id mentioned and a syntax error

Comment: this question is answered. thanks everyone

Comment: I'll just mention that as you've tagged your question `jquery`, you could save some typing with `$("selector").html("new content");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a period in between `document` and `querySelector` :

```
document.querySelector("#field_2_31 label").innerHTML = 'New label';
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you put that period in your answer?

Comment: and it would of been helpful if I put that period in my code... guess what it now works...

Comment: The selector is also wrong (for the HTML listed). It would need to be `"li#\\3123 label"` (because you have to escape that initial `1` as `\31`, which in a string literal is `\\31` of course) or `"li[id='123'] label"`. *(not my dv)*

Comment: I had thought of that, but html posted seemed like it was only example html, whereas the javascript seemed like he copy and pasted it, so I wasn't sure I should try and change it. And Yobd, apparen't it worked?

Comment: why did this answer get down voted? It was the answer

Comment: @OceansOnPluto yep, just a silly typo could of saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a discrepancy in how you edited the example for this post, but you are selecting `li` with id `field_2_31`, and your `li` has an id `123`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<li id="field_2_31" class="xxx">
  <label class="xxx" for="xxx">Something</label>
</li>
```

**JS :**

```
 document.querySelector('li#field_2_31 label').innerHTML = 'New label';
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmhav36u/2/) to worked example.